# Why were these two words combined?

Tags: python

I am using [Jupyter Notebook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPython#Project_Jupyter).

in: '''strvar = python '''

in :''' "learn" + strvar '''

out:  learn python

---

in: ''' "learn" + strvar '''

out: learnpython

Comment: Please edit your question to be more readable.

Comment: What is it you're trying to do? Your question is poorly formatted and hard to understand.

Comment: Please provide _exact_ code we can run ourselves without changes to see your problem. Right now the quoting is invalid, so the described code doesn't actually run. Maybe test at an online repl, like https://ideone.com/ or https://repl.it/, to make sure what you're showing us produces the problem in environments other than your own?

Answer (score 0):

The code should look like this:

```
strvar = "python"
print("learn", strvar)
```

Your mistake was doing a plus instead of a comma.